# A high level worker

Tags: word-choice

Do you say a "a high level worker", a middle level worker", and "a low level worker" to describe how much people earn?

Comment: I wouldn't advise it; better to say something like 'a person in a highly-paid job', 'a person on an average salary' and 'a person in a poorly-paid job'.

Comment: I agree with Kate.  "High-level" (or middle, or low) sound like they're describing positions in a company, or maybe levels of skill, but not pay.

Comment: Agreed. "Level" refers to the amount of responsibility one has within a working environment. A department head at a corporation might be considered "mid-level" and earn $300,000 per year. A department head at an American community college might also be considered "mid-level" while earning $80,000 per year.

Comment: …unless you're discussing steeplejacks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call them "high wage earner" and "low wage earner".

In "x level worker", level refers to the skill level, not the pay scale.